# How can I check that a window has been closed in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

For example, I have JavaScript like this:

```
windowHandle = window.open('http://www.irt.org/','testWindow','height=200,width=200');
```

I would like to check whether the 'testWindow' is closed and run a function if it is.

I have Googled this problem but so far all I found is:

```
if (testWindow.close) {..}
```

which is only run once. So I am wondering if there is an event triggered when a window is closed?

Comment: You should be able to attach a method to onbeforeunload. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Comment: onunload is probably better.. :)

Comment: Thanks, I have also come up with this , the only problem is I am uploading some file, so if the user close the window before upload is finished, the onbeforeunload event will not trigger  (Since all javascript is loaded only when upload file has done?)

Comment: that means I need to place an event in the main page instead of place the onunload event at the window dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a lightbox rather than a window.open for a task such as this. Most of the time it would be better to keep the user embedded into your site especially if you're doing something like an upload.

I've used colorbox to do similar tasks in the past. Here's a link http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Then you would just attach a callback to the closed event of the colorbox

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could find a better implementation in [MDN best practices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.open#Best_practices)

> **Code snippet from MDN**

```
var windowObjectReference = null; // global variable

function openFFPromotionPopup() {
  if(windowObjectReference == null || windowObjectReference.closed)
  /* if the pointer to the window object in memory does not exist
     or if such pointer exists but the window was closed */

  {
    windowObjectReference = window.open("http://www.spreadfirefox.com/",
   "PromoteFirefoxWindowName", "resizable,scrollbars,status");
    /* then create it. The new window will be created and
       will be brought on top of any other window. */
  }
  else
  {
    windowObjectReference.focus();
    /* else the window reference must exist and the window
       is not closed; therefore, we can bring it back on top of any other
       window with the focus() method. There would be no need to re-create
       the window or to reload the referenced resource. */
  };
}
```

In this way you can reliably determine whether the window is closed or not.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For file upload, you might want to try an invisible iframe hack, rather than a separate window.  Or a lightbox as suggested by Matthew Bucci above.